# load multi-line fixture field from django

Tags: python, django

In the fixture (in yaml), I set a multi-line field:

```
  fields:
    code: > 
            print(1)
            print(2)
            print(3)
```

Then I tried to read it by

```
print(code)
```

however it prints out

```
print(1) print(2) print(3)
```

without line breaks...

How can I init multiline fields in django fixtures?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use literal style, introduced by `|` instead of `>`: http://michael.f1337.us/2010/03/30/482836205/